How can I load copied Libraries to Anaconda packages
Because the company does not allow Internet connection from the internal computer, so I installed the libraries from my personal laptop and copied them to the company computer, but I did not see it appear on Anaconda's Package list. In my case it is dash module.


How should I do to update it to Anaconda packages list. Thank you.

I don't think you can install the package offline by moving the installed libraries from one computer to another because the installation process might build binaries from the first computer specs and configuration that might be incompatible when moving to another computer. To install anaconda packages with no internet connection, you should first download the tar.bz2 file of the package on anaconda repository on the computer that can connect to the internet and then transfer the tar.bz2 to the no internet computer and install the package on it using the command
conda install --offline <path to tar.bz2 file>


Thank you, I know that I can install packages with whl file or tar file, but I read somewhere that I can copy installed packages as well.
